# 3 Column footer sitting on left hand side - html

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to have a 3 column footer but everything i try, the text just sits on left-hand side. the latest below, has the columns on top of each other on the left. Background color and font do not work and on the index page, font seems to be bold for some reason.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer-container {
  background-color: #99cc99;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

footer {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: #99cc99;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

footer-heading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

footer-heading h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

footer-heading a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

footer-heading a:hover {
  color: #336633;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-container">

  <div class="footer">

    <div class="footer-heading footer-1">

      <h3>ADDRESS</h3>
      <p>1234 Sandy Beach Road, <br> Queenscliffe, New Zealand</p>

    </div>

    <div class="footer-heading footer-2">
      <h3>CONTACT</h3>
      <p>Sally Sharp <br> Tel: (00) 1234 1122</div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-heading footer-3">
    <h3>QUICK LINKS</h3>

    <a href="About/About.html#Ammenities">Ammenities</a><br>
    <a href="About/About.html#Availability">Availability</a><br>
    <a href="About/About.html#Cancellation Policy">Cancellation Policy</a><br>
    <a href="About/About.html#Location">Location</a><br>
    <a href="About/About.html#What's nearby">What's nearby</a>

  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had an extra `</div>` in your HTML at the end of `.footer-heading.footer-2`. Further, the syntax for a class in CSS selectors is `.className`. None of your CSS rules targeting classes included the `.` character before the className.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer-container {
  background-color: #99cc99;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

.footer {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: #99cc99;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer-heading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

.footer-heading h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.footer-heading a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.footer-heading a:hover {
  color: #336633;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-container">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-heading footer-1">
      <h3>ADDRESS</h3>
      <p>1234 Sandy Beach Road, <br> Queenscliffe, New Zealand</p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-heading footer-2">
      <h3>CONTACT</h3>
      <p>Sally Sharp <br> Tel: (00) 1234 1122
    </div>

    <div class="footer-heading footer-3">
      <h3>QUICK LINKS</h3>

      <a href="About/About.html#Ammenities">Ammenities</a><br>
      <a href="About/About.html#Availability">Availability</a><br>
      <a href="About/About.html#Cancellation Policy">Cancellation Policy</a><br>
      <a href="About/About.html#Location">Location</a><br>
      <a href="About/About.html#What's nearby">What's nearby</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And this is a great example of why it is worth keeping the code tidy rather than allowing breaks and spaces all over the place.

Comment: @ David. I thought this was going to be it. but no, nothing changed. I'm new to this, does that mean i have something wrong else where.?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Post an edit to your question with your updated code demonstrating what issues you're facing. From your snippet alone, my edits solve the problem you've stated in your question--There are 3 columns that are no longer left-aligned. If you need clarification on what I've changed, I'm happy to answer what questions you have.